# Bootstrap modal - close modal, refresh modal, reopen modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I am working on upgrading a photo gallery (the standard ones don't allow the amount of text I need for some photos). Everything works, but when I run code on buttons to navigate to the previous or next photo, the modal closes, the code to update the modal for the new photo runs, but the modal does not re-open. However, if I insert an alert after closing the modal, everything works as expected.

I have tried a variety of things including writing to the console, but that doesn't affect anything. I tried a "sleep" function where the alert is in the example above, but it executed before the modal was closed, so did not have a positive effect (other than waiting for the modal to close). Commenting out the alert in the code above runs the code in "open_gallery_form()", but the code that displays the modal does not fire.

```js
function nav_button_click(event_code, ep_id) {
  // close current version of modal form:
  $("#imageModal").modal('hide');

  // the form won't re-open without this which is frustrating ...
  // tried a "sleep" routine but that fires before the form is closed (above),
  // so is useless ... 
  // console.log("navigating"); console log doesn't do anything
  alert("navigating"); // please don't change the code

  // call code to refresh with new image and text, updated buttons, etc.
  // and display modal
  open_gallery_form(event_code, ep_id);
}

// More code here, please.
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

More markup here, please.

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You should be able to put a simple demo of this in a snippet using the post editor.

Comment: Per isherwood -- there is no "simple" demo I can put together, this uses Ajax, PHP and a lot more to put everything together. I cannot create a "simple" version. My big question is finding a way to deal with the need to wait or something (the alert as shown seems to do what is needed, but is not optimal) between closing the modal, and the code to re-display it ... everything up to the re-display of the modal works fine without the alert.

Comment: You probably can. It's mostly a matter of a button and some modal markup, along with a simplified version of your second function. At any rate, try wrapping it in a zero-delay timeout: `setTimeout(() => open_gallery_form(event_code, ep_id))`

Comment: If that doesn't work, use Boostrap's [hidden event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#events) to call your second function. That's probably the more proper way to do it anyway.

Comment: I just tried the settimeout that you suggested, but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried working with the hidden event, but the difficulty is that sometimes I just want the form to close. If the user clicks outside the window, or uses the close button in the modal, it should simply close, not make a call to the open_gallery_form() function.

Comment: A bit of looking on the web, and I found this worked:
`setTimeout(() => {  open_gallery_form(event_code, ep_id) }, "1000");` -- Thanks. I think this will do what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments from isherwood the following:

```
setTimeout(() => {  open_gallery_form(event_code, ep_id) }, "1000");
```

Works to delay and then call the function, a 1 second delay seems to be enough. I am calling this done and working.

Comment: A one second delay doesn't sound like great UX. Is that what you _want_, or is it what you're settling for?

Comment: Tinkering, I was able to bring it down to 1/2 second. For now it is fine.